# Javascript Console in Tizen Browser

Tags: javascript, console, tizen

I was wondering, is it possible to view the javascript console in the native Samsung TV Browser?

I've seen a lot of posts regarding debugging your own applications, but nothing about the native Samsung apps.

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen similar post here in this link( https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/javascript-console-tizen-browser ) Please check here.

Comment: Haha, I asked that question too!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any kind of debug window that displays a console (though there may or may not be one).

What definitely is possible is to use *Weinre* and remotely display console output by connecting your device as a client to your *Weinre* server. You **will then not** see the console in the native Samsung TV browser, but you **will** see the output of your native Samsung TV browser in your local browser.